# Ansible synchronize module is not replacing user variable with exact user name

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I tried many ways to fix the below problem, but I was not lucky enough.
I have the below inventories;

#cat inventory/common/group_vars/all/inventory_pwd.yml

remote1_user: "devops"

#cat inventory/nonprod/fdc/group_vars/all/inventory.txt

[remote]
x.x.x.x  ansible_ssh_user="{{ remote1_user }}"  ansible_port=22 ansible_password="test@12"

And I am running this below playbook to copy files from control machine to a remote machine;

pb.yml

```
---
- name: "Copy test"
  hosts: remote
  become: true
  tasks:

    - name: Copying content to the remote vm
      synchronize:
        src: /ansible/playbooks/Hello
        dest: /home/devops/
      delegate_to: localhost
```

In the controller machine I logged as root user, and the user to connect with remote server is devops.

But, after executing the playbook I am getting the below error;

ansible-playbook -vvv -i inventory/common -i inventory/nonprod/fdc/group_vars/all/inventory.txt pb.yml

```
TASK [Copying content to the remote vm] *********************************************************************************************task path: /ansible/playbooks/pb.yml:9
fatal: [x.x.x.x -> localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "sshpass -d3 /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null --rsync-path=sudo rsync --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L /ansible/playbooks/Hello {{remote1_user}}@x.x.x.x:/home/devops/",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_local_rsync_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "_local_rsync_path": "rsync",
            "_substitute_controller": false,
            "archive": true,
            "checksum": false,
            "compress": true,
            "copy_links": false,
            "delete": false,
            "dest": "{{remote1_user}}@x.x.x.x:/home/devops/",
            "dest_port": null,
            "dirs": false,
            "existing_only": false,
            "group": null,
            "link_dest": null,
            "links": null,
            "mode": "push",
            "owner": null,
            "partial": false,
            "perms": null,
            "private_key": null,
            "recursive": null,
            "rsync_opts": [],
            "rsync_path": "sudo rsync",
            "rsync_timeout": 0,
            "set_remote_user": true,
            "src": "/ansible/playbooks/Hello",
            "ssh_args": null,
            "times": null,
            "verify_host": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "remote username contains invalid characters\r\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]\n",
    "rc": 255
}
```

Here the '"dest": "{{ remote1_user }}@x.x.x.x:/home/devops/"' should be like 'devops@x.x.x.x:/home/devops/'. However, it is not replacing 'remote1_user' with 'devops'.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried renaming all instances of `remote1_user` to something that doesn't contain a number?

Comment: Yes, I tried with remote_user also. But, no change, the exception is still there

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the problem but I've always coded the variables witha space before and after braces - {{ remote1_user }}@x.x.x.x:/home/devops/

Comment: Yes.  In fact, the documentation starting point for setting and using variables in Ansible is https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html and all through the examples of referencing (using) variables there is space between the variable name and the surrounding '{{' and '}}'

Comment: I tried with space before and after the braces for variables - {{ remote1_user }}. But, I still have that error

Answer (score -1):

There may be a problem with the names - not sure ansible is finding the variable file.  If inventory/nonprod/fdc/group_vars/all/inventory.txt is your host file try changing it to inventory/nonprod/fdc/inventory.txt and then change the group var file to inventory/nonprod/fdc/group_vars/all/inventory_pwd.yml